# Divide list code snippet I dont understand

Tags: prolog

can you explain this piece of code for me?

```
teile_Liste([],[],[]).
teile_Liste([X],[X],[]).
teile_Liste([X,Y|Liste],[X|Liste1],[Y|Liste2]) :-
    teile_Liste(Liste,Liste1,Liste2).

?- teile_Liste([a,b,c,d,e],X,Y).
X = [a, c, e],
Y = [b, d] .
```

I don't understands whats happing there. I even looked into it with trace but that didn't help me either.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`teile_Liste/3` is true for the special case of all arguments being empty lists:

```
teile_Liste([],[],[]).
```

`teile_Liste/3` is also true for the special case of two identical one-element list on positions 1 and 2, and the empty list on position 3.

```
teile_Liste([X],[X],[]).
```

In the one other case that shall be true we use induction:

The case is described as

```
teile_Liste([X,Y|Liste],[X|Liste1],[Y|Liste2])
```

So the argument at position 1 must be a list of at least 2 elements, which also appear as element of lists at argument positions 2 and 3, distributed.

But we also want to say something about the smaller lists `Liste`, `Liste1`, `Liste2`, which cannot be whatever they are but which must follow the recursive relationship:

```
teile_Liste(Liste,Liste1,Liste2).
```

Evidently this is a specification to relate three lists in a way such that the first list's contents are distributed over the other two lists. This specification is complete enough for Prolog to build one list if two other are giving, or to fail the query if that is not possible (as in `teile_Liste([a],[b],[X,Y])`: NOPE!). Alternatively if all three lists are given, Prolog can verify that the relationship holds.

And so the proof proceeds:

**QUERY**

```
teile_Liste([a,b,c,d,e],X,Y).
```

Only the head of the 3rd clause matches that query. It's a rule. The rule's variables are set to be as follows by unification:

**CLAUSE MATCH 1**

```
teile_Liste([a,b|[c,d,e]],[a|Liste1],[b|Liste2]) :-
 teile_Liste([c,d,e],Liste1,Liste2).
```

According to the principles of Prolog, we shall now prove the body of the matching rule:

```
teile_Liste([c,d,e],Liste1,Liste2).
```

**CLAUSE MATCH 2**

Again, only the 3rd clause matches (rule application B):

```
teile_Liste([c,d|[e]],[c|Liste1],[d|Liste2]) :-
    teile_Liste([e],Liste1,Liste2).
```

According to the principles of Prolog, we shall now prove the body of the matching rule:

```
teile_Liste([e],Liste1,Liste2).
```

**CLAUSE MATCH 3**

Only the head of the second clause matches.

This is a "base case match", i.e. we match a *fact* instead of a *rule*; there won't be any recursion. All the rules encountered have also been completely worked off. So we are done with "query success". We just need to check what happens to the variables of the query. These are printed out by the Prolog Toplevel.

So we match the fact:

```
teile_Liste([e],[e],[])
```

thus forcing the previously-unknown values of `List1` and `List2` to be `[e]` and `[]`, respectively.

These are same variables than the ones of CLAUSE MATCH 2, so the head *there* can now be written

```
teile_Liste([c,d|[e]],[c|[e]],[d|[]])
```

or simpler:

```
teile_Liste([c,d,e],[c,e],[d])
```

This means that for CLAUSE MATCH 1:

```
Liste1 = [c,e]
Liste2 = [d]
```

so the head there is equal to

```
teile_Liste([a,b|[c,d,e]],[a|[c,e]],[b|[d]])
```

or simpler:

```
teile_Liste([a,b,c,d,e],[a,c,e],[b,d])
```

and thus the variables of the query are:

```
X = [a,c,e]
Y = [b,d]
```

...which is what is printed out.

Answer (score 1):

`teile_Liste` describes a relation, such that

1. the triple `( [], [], [])` is in the relation;
2. the triple `( [X], [X], [])` is in the relation, whatever value the variable `X` has (or none); this means the first two argument are the same, one-element, list, and the third argument is an empty list;
3. the triple `( [X, Y | Z], [X | Z1], [Y | Z2])` is in the relation, if
   `( Z, Z1, Z2)` is in this relation, whatever the values of `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `Z1` and `Z2`,
   where each reference to a variable with the same name refers to the same value:

   ```erlang
   relation( [X, Y | Z], [X | Z1], [Y | Z2] ) :-
     relation(       Z,       Z1 ,      Z2  ).
   ```

This means that relation `teile_Liste( A, B, C)` holds

```erlang
    teile_Liste( A, B, C) :-
```

whenever

```erlang
          A = [X, Y    | Z],              % and
          B = [X             | Z1],         % and
          C = [   Y                | Z2],     % and the relation
          teile_Liste(   Z,    Z1,   Z2 ).    % holds.
```

meaning,

- the first argument is a list starting with `X` and `Y` and having more elements in it after that, `Z`;
- the second list argument starts with `X` and has more elements in it, `Z1`;
- the third list argument starts with `Y` and has more elements in it, `Z2`;
- `Z, Z1, Z2` relate in the same fashion, so overall it is:

  ```erlang
   [X, Y, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, ....., XN, YN]
   [X,    X1,     X2,     ....., XN    ]
   [   Y,     Y1,     Y2, .....,     YN]
  ```

  (when recursion ends on the `([], [], [])` case, so, the first list argument's length is *even*), *or*

  ```erlang
   [X, Y, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, ....., XN1, YN1, XN]
   [X,    X1,     X2,     ....., XN1    ,  XN]
   [   Y,     Y1,     Y2, .....,      YN1    ]
  ```

  (when recursion ends on the `([XN], [XN], [])` case, so, the first list argument's length is *odd*).